# ИП с фамилией склоняется или нет

Tags: согласование

Доверенное лицо ИП Горячей или доверенное лицо ИП Горячая.... Изначально фамилия Горячая!

Answer (score 2):

**Предупреждение:** я не являюсь юристом, и мой ответ не имеет юридической силы, а отражает лишь моё, непрофессиональное, понимание законов.

ИП, несмотря на красивую аббривеатуру, является физическим лицом, наделенным определенными полномочиями. В отдельных ситуациях ИП может нести ответственность *как юридическое лицо*, но это не дает ему таковой статус.

У ИП нет названия, поскольку у физического лица не может быть названия. В частности, если обратиться к 5·1 и 5·2 ФЗ-129 "О государственной регистрации юридических лиц и индивидуальных предпринимателей", то в тексте четко указывается, что для юридического лица регистрируются:

> а) полное и (в случае, если имеется) сокращенное наименование, фирменное наименование для коммерческих организаций на русском языке. В случае, если в учредительных документах юридического лица его наименование указано на одном из языков народов Российской Федерации и (или) на иностранном языке, в едином государственном реестре юридических лиц указывается также наименование юридического лица на этих языках.

А для ИП:

> а) фамилия, имя и (в случае, если имеется) отчество на русском языке (для иностранных граждан и лиц без гражданства такие сведения дополнительно указываются с помощью букв латинского алфавита на основании сведений, содержащихся в документе, удостоверяющем личность в соответствии с законодательством Российской Федерации).

То есть, лингвистически, *ИП* играет ту же роль в предложении, что и расшифровка *индивидуальный предприниматель*.

Соответственно, у ИП фамилия склоняется так же, как если бы вместо *ИП* были слова *доктор*, *гражданин*, *доцент* и т.п. То есть, если фамилия склоняемая, то и тут пишется вариант в требуемой форме:

*Доверенное лицо ИП Горячей*

Рекомендую, однако, указывать и инициалы ИП, а не только лишь одну фамилию.

**Upd.** Добавлю одно исключение. Если ИП Иванову И.И. придет в голову зарегистрировать торговую марку "ИП Иванов И.И." (или ещё каким-то образом создать аналогичный бренд), то нужно будет при упоминании *марки* (не самого ИП), использовать несклоняемый вариант:

*Люблю я пирожки "ИП Иванов И.И.".*

**НО**

*Пирожки были поставлены ИП Ивановым И.И.*